# What's the difference between textDocument/Definition, textDocument/implementation?

Tags: language-server-protocol

I read through the LSP [specification](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specifications/specification-3-14) but I fail to understand the difference between the goto definition and goto implementation requests.

[Goto Definition Request](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specifications/specification-3-14/#textDocument_definition)

> The go to definition request is sent from the client to the server to resolve the definition location of a symbol at a given text document position.

[Goto Implementation Request](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specifications/specification-3-14/#textDocument_implementation)

> The go to implementation request is sent from the client to the server to resolve the implementation location of a symbol at a given text document position.

Comment: As far as I understand in a typical editor, the "go to def" (https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specifications/specification-3-15/#textDocument_declaration) of a reference to a method that is defined in an interface would take you to the defining occurrence in the interface. The "go to impl" (https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specifications/specification-3-15/#textDocument_implementation) of a referenced method defined in an interface would pop open a list of defining occurrences of all methods that implement the interface method, and then let you choose.